# Global Variables

Tags: wpf, vb.net

In my WPF applciation I would like to use global variable, the purpose is like to store the current user information etc, The problem is that, there are two methods for it and they are:

Application.Current.Properties vs My.Settings

I know that using My.Settings, the changes will be stored and when the app restarts or reopened, they would load the last saved ones, I dont want it this way.  Could you please clarify is Application.Current.Property solve my problem or is there any other method for this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just create a static or singleton class to hold all your values, if your going to reload them every time the program is going to run anyway?

```
Public Class Globals

    Public Shared Property One As String
        Get
            Return TryCast(Application.Current.Properties("One"), String)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Application.Current.Properties("One") = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shared Property Two As Integer
        Get
            Return Convert.ToInt32(Application.Current.Properties("Two"))
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            Application.Current.Properties("Two") = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: No, i dont want to reload them when program starts.  So is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: Sorry I think I'm confused. I thought you didn't want the last values to be saved and loaded when the program restarts?

Comment: Yes, I dont want them to be saved, I think the Application.Current.Property can be used, but want to know if there is any more methods to achieve it.

Comment: However, could you please tell me why or how or is it better than Application.Current.Properties?

Comment: Reviewed it and tested, the procedure you said is lot more simple when compared to the Application property.   Thank you very much.