# How to have a global Dictionary in VB.NET/WPF application to save data from different windows?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls, vb.net-2010

I am new to VB.NET and WPF.

I am building a "Questionnaire" app. Users will be presented sequentially with different questions/tasks (windows). After they respond on each question/task and press a "submit" button a new window will open with a new question/task, and previous window will close. After each question, when the button is pressed, I need to store data to some global object. After all questions are answered the data of this object should be written out to the output file.

I figured out that Dictionary will be the best to store the results after each window.

I am not sure how, where to create this global Dictionary and how to access it. Should I use View Model? If yes, can you give an example? Or, should it be just a simple class with shared property? (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657053/pass-data-between-wpf-windows))

**EDIT 2: I tried many different ways recommended online**

GlobalModule:

```
Module GlobalModule
   Public Foo As String
End Module
```

GlobalVariables:

```
Public Class GlobalVariables
   Public Shared UserName As String = "Tim Johnson"
   Public Shared UserAge As Integer = 39
End Class
```

Global properties:

```
Public Class Globals

Public Shared Property One As String
    Get
        Return TryCast(Application.Current.Properties("One"), String)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        Application.Current.Properties("One") = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared Property Two As Integer
    Get
        Return Convert.ToInt32(Application.Current.Properties("Two"))
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        Application.Current.Properties("Two") = value
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

Here is where I save the data to global variables/properties in the first window. I need to store data in this subroutine before closing an old window and opening a new window. I use MessageBox just for testing.

```
Private Sub btnEnter_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click

    Dim instructionWindow As InstructionsWindow

    instructionWindow = New InstructionsWindow()

    Application.Current.Properties("number") = textBoxValue.Text

    Globals.One = "2"
    Globals.Two = 3

    MessageBox.Show("GlobalVariables: UserName=" & GlobalVariables.UserName & " UserAge=" & GlobalVariables.UserAge)

    GlobalVariables.UserName = "Viktor"
    GlobalVariables.UserAge = 34

    GlobalModule.Foo = "Test Foo"


    'testing if it saved tha value
    'MessageBox.Show(Application.Current.Properties("number"))

    Application.Current.MainWindow.Close()

    instructionWindow.ShowDialog()

End Sub
```

Next subroutine is where I am trying to retrieve the value from global Properties/variables in the second window, but message boxes come out empty. There might also the case that I am assigning values in a wrong way, or not reading them in a right way (casting?) :

```
Private Sub FlowDocReader_Initialized(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FlowDocReader.Initialized

    ' Get a reference to the Application base class instance.
    Dim currentApplication As Application = Application.Current

    MessageBox.Show(currentApplication.Properties("number"))

    MessageBox.Show("One = " & Globals.One & " Two = " & Globals.Two)

    MessageBox.Show("GlobalVariables: UserName=" & GlobalVariables.UserName & " UserAge=" & GlobalVariables.UserAge)

    MessageBox.Show("GlobalModule.Foo = " & GlobalModule.Foo)

    Dim filename As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\instructions.txt"

    Dim paragraph As Paragraph = New Paragraph()
    paragraph.Inlines.Add(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename))
    Dim document As FlowDocument = New FlowDocument(paragraph)
    FlowDocReader.Document = document

End Sub
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make public `Dictionary` property for form and put your dictionry to this property or make constructor with  `Dictionary` argument.

Comment: You can create dictionary variable  in main form and set it to child forms. And it was only one dictionary, beacuse when you set child form property you set reference to dictionary. more info about reference types see on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx Sorry fo my bad english.

Comment: Frank59, thanks. It worked. ByRef was a good idea. I was not thinking outside of the box, and was stuck with the idea to define some sort of Global variable. I am still surprised no of the "Global variable" ways worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You already have this dictionary `Application.Properties`
Look here, [please](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.properties.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I tried this option, but I cannot get the value back from the properties in the second window. I'll post two subroutines where I store the data to Properties and then where I retrieve it in the second window.

Comment: I can offer you to comment out the first call to MessageBox and check whether value isstored.

Comment: And you have only the one place in the code where you set the property, don't you?

Comment: Two subroutines above are the only places where I use Application.Current.Properties("number"). Thanks.

Comment: I tried to test this example, and it produced an empty MessageBox too. Maybe, I should not try to read properties in _initialized() event, or there is some settings missing for Application.Properties.

Comment: Sorry, the example I mentioned is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541630/global-variables

Comment: I updated my post after I tried many different options. Nothing is working so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can define a dictionary (list of lists) as follows at the beginning of a form or in a module

```
 Dim dic As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))
```

As the user completes questions on a form, write the partucular form number and query results to a single record in the dic before going to the next form (place this code into the "Next" button):

```
 'Assume q1response=3, q2response=4,..., qpresponse="text", etc.
 Dim myValues As New List(Of String)
 myValues.Add(formname)
 myValues.Add(q1response)
 myValues.Add(q2response)
 .
 .
 myValues.Add(qpresponse)
 dic.Add(username, myValues)
```

When a user is done, there will be multiple records in the dictionary, each of which starts with their name and is followed by question responses.  You can loop through multiple dictionary records, where each record is for a user using the following:

```
For Each DictionaryEntry In dic 'this loops through dic entries
  Dim str As List(Of String) = DictionaryEntry.Value
    'here you can do whatever you want with results while you read through dic records
    'username will be = str(0)
    'formname will be str(1)
    'q1 response on "formname" will be str(2)
    'q2 response on "formname" will be str(3)
    'q3 response on "formname" will be str(4)
    ...

Next
```

The trick is that there will be multiple dictionary records with results for one user, where record one can have results like "John Doe,page1,q1,q2,q3" and record 2 will be "John Doe,page2,q4,q5,q6."  Specifically, the "str" in the above loop will be an array of string data containing all the items within each dictionary record, that is, in str(0), str(1), str(2),...  This is the information you need to work with or move, save, analyze, etc.

Comment: The main problem was how to share this object between different windows without loosing data. I solved it by creating this object in a first window, and then passing it ByRef to the following windows. I do not like this design, but I could not get work other option listed here and on the web. I'd like rather to have some class, or module, that I can use in all windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can always put all the code I provided in a class (which will be independent of any form) and dimension the sic is a Sub New in this class, with the updating .Add values lines in their own sub in this same class). Then just Dim Updater As New MyNewClassName.  Call the Updater in each continue button using Call Updater.SubNameWithAddValues(q1,q2,...qp).  It won't matter where you are in your program since you using a specific class.  The one thing I noticed with my code is that you can only use the line that adds the "key" or the username once, so use it after the last query -so put it in a Sub Finished in your new class and call as Call Updater.Finished(username,q30,q31,last)